# Move the selected menu option at first position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a top menu bar with multiple menu items.

```js
$('.subpage_top_nav li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='subpage_top_nav'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>All WildLife</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Kavango</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Northeast Greenland</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Pacific Remote</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Papahānaumokuākea </center>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to hold the first value 'All WildLife' in the second position always?

Example: On page load 'All WildLife' comes at first position and when I select "Northeast Greenland" then 'All WildLife' goes on Second position, but again when I click on 'Pacific Remote', "All wildLife" option remains on second but the first option move to third and 'Pacific Remote' moves to first.

Thank You for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you require you could add a class to the `li` which holds 'All Wildlife' and then `prepend()` that first, before you `prepend()` the clicked item. This way it will always appear second in the list after a selection is made. Try this:

```js
var $all = $('.subpage_top_nav li.all');

$('.subpage_top_nav li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().prepend($all).prepend(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='subpage_top_nav'>
  <ul>
    <li class="all">
      <a href='#'>
        <center>All WildLife</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Kavango</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Northeast Greenland</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Pacific Remote</center>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <center>Papahānaumokuākea </center>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```